# iOS Realm with Swift codable

Tags: ios, swift, realm, codable

I have a project with two List fields that are used by the RealmSwift for its data base.  Following is my Model

```
@objcMembers public class MyModel : Object , Codable{
dynamic var Id : String = ""
dynamic var Name: String = ""
dynamic var Favorites : List<String>? = nil 
dynamic var Subjects " List<UserSubject>? = nil 
}
```

In this model you can see there are 2 Fields of List and they are creating problem. I have **init** in my model two but not sharing for the sake of compact post size. however I have tried [this](https://medium.com/@Kaakati/swift-4-codable-realm-database-list-59887a3fd4a4) but got no luck

I am still facing following compiler error.

> The 'MyModel' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

I do not know now How to handle this??? Is any 1 of you have this problem? tell me how to solve this?

Comment: The link is leading to a 404 page

Comment: let me check....

Comment: @joern question is updated

Comment: Is `UserSubject` also `Codable`?

Comment: yes it is also codable. The point is List is not codable in swift

Comment: Have you implemented [`encode(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable/2893603-encode) and [`init(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable/2894081-init)?

Comment: no what is that please guide me throguh, I am new to it @nayem

Comment: Well, you should forget about *Realm* for now. First you need to understand what `Codable` stands for. How you can encode and decode manually. There are plenty of resources out there, just try googling. Here are some reference: [this](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375), [this](https://hackernoon.com/codable-in-swift4-e24f7cc253da), [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/382-encoding-decoding-and-serialization-in-swift-4).

Comment: bro I have read many like these links, the only thing that is creating problem is LIST that is used by realm

Comment: Yes! `List` is a type from Realm. And this shouldn't be `Codable` by default. You have to encode/decode this type manually. And that's the reason you have to implement `encode(to:)` and `init(from:)`. The link you have provided with your question does that and you might have missed that part.

Comment: please add that in answer the part I missed